# Control Variations in a Measurement (Temperature Sensor)

Tags: control-theory

I have a temperature sensor and I want to normalize the sensor values. The measured room has a pretty constant temperature but the sensor shows slightly different values e.g. `30.20, 30.00, 30.30, 30.00`. For display reasons, I want to have it less variation. Also sometimes it deviates unreasonable e.g. `30.00, 30.00, 10.00, 30.00, 30.00`. But it can change from one moment to another also in a reasonable way e.g. opening a window: `30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 25.00, 15.00,10.00`

I do not have target curve otherwise I thought about a PID.

At the moment I sum the last values and build an average. What can I do to

1. normalize the output values
2. eliminate runaway values

Comment: Maybe if the change is too big eliminate the runaway value otherwise you can still averaging the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple [lowpass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) filter will probably solve the problem. It is easy to implement and you can adjust how much you want to filter with the time constant.

Here is an example of a low-pass filter in actual code. It's technically Python but reads like pseudo-code. It takes a list of temperature values as input and outputs the filtered values as a list.

```
Input:  input_series, time_constant
Output: output_series


output_series = []
output_series.append(input_series[0])

for current_unfiltered_value in input_series:
    previous_filtered_value = output_series[-1]

    B = 1.0 / time_constant
    A = 1.0 - B

    new_filtered_value = (A * previous_filtered_value
                          + B * current_unfiltered_value)

    output_series.append(new_filtered_value)

return output_series
```

The downside of using lowpass filters is that it introduces phase lag. The filtered value will lag slightly behind the measured signal, depending on the time constant. A highly filtered signal will lag more than a less filtered signal.

There are other filters you can use for better filtering result. For example the [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) or the [Alpha-beta filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_beta_filter). They are both model-based, which means you have to make a model for your temperature changes for it to work. There is an excellent [notebook](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python) on Github that introduces these filters if you are unfamiliar with them.

I would personally go with a simple lowpass filter in the beginning. If you don't control a process based on the filtered values, but want to filter the values to make them prettier in a user interface, then that's usually more than good enough.

For eliminating runaway values I would calculate the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of the measured signal at every timestep (you could, for example, calculate the variance for the last 50 samples). If the calculated variance passes a certain threshold then it can be assumed to be a spike, which can then be rejected.

Comment: Thx I will try with the lowpass. Indeed the Kalman & Bayesian sounds like the correct (but maybe too sophisticated solution).